# Access File in Mac using java.io.file

Tags: java, file, osx-snow-leopard

I am using `java.io.File` to create a new file in java.On Mac-Os I am using the same code which was working fine on windows but its not working on mac.

I am using

```
File file = new File(path);
```

to create a new file.

In windows:
I used `String path = "C:\test\1.html";`
It was working fine.

On a Mac:
I want to create file at `"/Users/pls/1.html"`
But it is throwing error as

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException : /Users/pls/1.html (No such file or directory)
```

Please help

Comment: Are you sure that the `/Users/pls` directory exists and that the file is inside that directory?

Comment: ... and that you have permission to read it?

Comment: Is it "/Users/pls/1.html" or "/users/pls/1.html"? (Note: the capitalization of U in the former case). Also, new File() just creates a file object, not a file. It will not throw any exception other than NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thilo, Main problem was due to permissions. Actually the directory in which i am writing the file has the permissions but the parent directory did not have write permissions. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Don't write separators manually,Use system Independent [File.separator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) instead.

```
String path = File.separator+"Users"+File.separator+"pls"+File.separator+"1.html";
File file = new File(path);
```

Comment: True, but I don't think this will help.